# How to show DigitalOcean private Spaces temporaryURL on Laravel?

Tags: laravel, digital-ocean, laravel-storage, digital-ocean-spaces, digital-ocean-apps

I have successfully generated a temporary link in laravel which works correctly locally but when I try to generate a link via Storage::temporaryUrl for the production environment, it does not work. The error message is this **"This driver does not support creating temporary URLs."**

The link works only with Storage::URL, but when I try to access it I get an Access Denied because it does not have a temporary key.

I was wondering if there is a way to generate a temporary URL for the link with temporary key.